# Recursos de C# copiar a un directorio especifico

Tags: c#, visual-studio, string

Buen día,

tengo una carpeta con archivos de recursos necesarios para crear un archivo PDF, pero en mi código los utilizo desde un directorio creado.Para no tener que modificar todo el código buscando las direcciones donde ocupo esos recursos, se me ha ocurrido copiar los archivos de mi carpeta Resources del proyecto. Mi problema es. ¿Al momento de publicar mi código, instalar mi programa en algún otro equipo, como puedo asegurarme que llame a ese directorio de resources para copiarlos al directorio que necesito?

```
string path = @"c:\PruebasPDF";//directorio a donde deseo mandar mis recursos.
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(resources))//directorio de donde tomare los recursos
            {
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
            }
```

[image: Recursos del proyecto]

Comment: Podes hacer que busque en el directorio de tu App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yo lo que suelo hacer es situar mis recursos en una carpeta localizada donde mismo tengo el ejecutable de la aplicación:

Dir_De_Mi-App\

```
          MiAPlicacion.exe

          \Recursos
```

En este escenario el tema sería así:

```
        //directorio a donde deseo mandar mis recursos.
        string path = @"c:\PruebasPDF";
        // Ruta de nuestro directorio de recursos
        string pathSRC = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +  @"\Recursos";
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        // Aquí tomamos los recursos de directorio pathSRC
        // donde los tenemos ubicados
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(pathSRC))
        {
            File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileName(file)), true);
        }
```

Comment: tu comentario fue el mas acertado a lo que buscaba, desafortunadamente esa metadologia la utilice y al pasarla a otro equipo, no conseguia el resultado esperado.
Mi teoria dice que esa es una forma de hacerlo y deberia funcionar, por lo que supongo tuve un error de sintaxis. esto use:` 
            string pathdestiny = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pathdestiny);
            `

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma tenes acceso al directorio de tu aplicacion y solo debes tener agregados tus archivos en la solucion.

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```